# JDBC Class.forName vs DriverManager.registerDriver

Tags: java, jdbc

Which is the difference from `forName` method vs `registerDriver` to load and register a JDBC driver?

Comment: `registerDriver` requires the driver to be available at compile time. Failing so (availability) on runtime would result in NoClassDefFoundError (which you usually would not like to deal with). `Class.forName` implies late binding and doesn't require the driver to be available on compile time.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[`Class.forName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) is not directly related to JDBC at all. It simply loads a class.

Most JDBC Driver classes register themselves in their static initializers by calling [`registerDriver()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html#registerDriver%28java.sql.Driver%29).

`registerDriver()` is the real call that you hardly ever need to call yourself (unless you write your own JDBC driver).

Note that in JDBC 4 you should not need *either of those* if your JDBC driver is up-to-date, as drivers can be found using the service location mechanisms instead (i.e. simply leave out that call and open your connection as usual). See the [documentaton of `DriverManager`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) for details:

> The DriverManager methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of `java.sql.Driver`. For example, to load the `my.sql.Driver` class, the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file would contain the entry:
>
> ```
> my.sql.Driver
> ```
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()`. Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using `Class.forName()` will continue to work without modification.

Comment: As an example take a look at [MySQL JDBC Driver source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.java.html). It calls `registerDriver` in its static initializer.

Comment: Ok, but If I use registerDriver than I must load the class into memory?

Comment: @xdevel2000: yes. Since `registerDriver()` takes an instance of the `Driver` class as the argument, you must have loaded that class before calling the method.

Comment: Driver d =  DriverManager.getDriver("jdbc:mysql://localhost"); do that?

Comment: @xdevel: I don't understand what you're trying to do. If all you want to do is to connect to a database and you've got a sufficiently modern JDBC driver, then you don't need any of `Class.forName()`, `registerDriver` or `getDriver()`. You'd simply call `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost")` without any other preparation. If you want to do something else, then please tell us what that is.

Comment: Ok, be patient :) my question is only for better understand the JDBC driver registration mechanism.

Comment: My case: tomcat 7, java 1.7, postgres jdbc4 with META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver setup, it started working after adding Class.forName() preceding DriverManager.getConnection().  I was able to get tomcat 6, java 1.6, postgres jdbc3 work without calling Class.forName() using JAVA_OPTS -Djdbc.drivers=org.postgresql.Driver that does not seem to work with tomcat 7.  Go figure!

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Is it true that if we call `.registerDriver` directly, then before that call, the driver's static initializer would run and call `.registerDriver` too, effectively giving us *two* calls to `.registerDriver`?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes, I would expect that to happen, and I don't know how the JDBC framework would react to that (I expect it to either ignore the second call or throw an exception on the second call, either way, the driver will be registered). As I wrote in the answer: there is really no reason to call `registerDriver` yourself unless you are writing your own JDBC driver.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Another post http://stackoverflow.com/a/1311085/632951 seems to claim that calling `registerDriver` twice may give us problems, since we get a *different* instance registered. Anyway, if there is no reason to call `registerDriver`, why is it `public` then?

Comment: @Pacerier, I don't actually see that claim there. It needs to be public, because drivers aren't magical beasts, they have to follow the same access rules as any other code. If it weren't public they also couldn't call it. Not all rules in an API specification can be encoded using access restrictions (that's true for almost all languages, not just Java).

Comment: You still need to call one of them when running some Java code in an Apache Ant task (except when using the Java task with fork=true) as it uses an already launched JVM and I have found no way to force the scan for (SPI) plugins except for the SPIs on images (see ImageIO.scanForPlugins()). If you find a smarter solution, let me know.

Answer (score 23):

Never call `DriverManager.registerDriver()` method manually. The JDBC spec requires a driver to register itself when the class is loaded, and the class is loaded via `Class.forName()`. In JDBC 4 the drivers are able to be loaded automatically just by being on the class path.

`DriverManager.registerDriver()` manually is potentially dangerous since it actually causes the Driver to be registered twice. If your code requires you to deregister a Driver to prevent a memory leak then you would only end up deregistering it once and leave a second instance registered.

Comment: if you call register, you will need to call deregister (that only normal I guess). Class.forName() has side effects that doesn't deregister the driver. I recall tomcat attempt to deregisters drivers loaded by the webapp on redeploy of the latter.

Comment: No, the `Driver` is required to call `DriverManager.register` itself. If you look at the source for `DriverManager`, calling `register` will add another `Driver` regardless of whether it is already registered. Likewise `deregister` will only remove one instance regardless of how many times it was registered. Short answer: don't do that.

Comment: @DavidO'Meara, If DriverManager.registerDriver() should never be called directly, why is it a public method?

Comment: @Pacerier It is public because driver implementations need to be able to call it to register themselves.

Answer (score -2):

In additaion to what Joachim Sauer already mentioned about JDBC 4 drivers, note that in practice you usually want to **inject** either an EntityManager (JPA) or a pooled DataSource (and use JdbcTemplate of Spring).

Comment: Yes, a dependency injection framework. E.g. you could use Java EE: configure the DB in the application server, then inject an EntityManager into your EJB: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqw.html#bnbqz
or else you could use Spring: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: There is no mention of Spring or any other frameworks that support injection in the question.