# Error: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:mysql:\\localhost:3306\Mysql" when JDBC Connection configuration in jmeter

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jmeter

i am configuring **JDBC Connection in jmeter 2.8**. Purpose is i need to place results of jmeter JDBC Request sampler(3 column data) in database table. I am using MySQL database. And also placed "**mysql-connector-java-5.1.24-bin.jar**" in jmeter "/lib" directory.

Problem is when i run the sampler it gives a message **"No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql:\localhost:3306\Mysql"** in Response data tab in Results Tree. I am missing something i don't know what it is.

can any one help me with necessary information to get me out of it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JDBC/MSQL: No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/jdbc-msql-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JDBC URL you specified is wrong. The error says you use the URL `jdbc:mysql:\localhost:3306\Mysql`. That is an incorrect URL.

You need to use:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Mysql
```