# No suitable Driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dname

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connectivity

I'm relatively new to java and have just started learning chow to connect mysql to java. This is my code to add details entered in java to a table in mysql:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    String Name = t1.getText();     
    String Mobile = t2.getText();
    String Email = t3.getText();
    try
    { 
        Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
        Connection con;
        con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cbse", "Mahima" , "mahima");

        Statement stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO contact VALUES ('"+Name+"','"+Mobile+"', '"+Email+"');";

        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How to fix the error??

Comment: possible duplicate of [No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql) - at least the answers there contain useful information how to solve the problem

Comment: @mschenk74 no, it's not. The JDBC URI looks OK.

Comment: What error exactly? Please post the exact message.

Comment: `Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");` doesn't make any sense. Are you sure the MySQL JDBC driver is in the classpath?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know it's wrong, but `DriverManager` should be on the classpath nevertheless. So the error must be somewhere else (probably no connector in classpath).

Comment: The `DriverManager` is part of the JRE, it does not make any sense to load it dynamically - especially if you have a (hard) reference to it in your Java class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java connectivity with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839321/java-connectivity-with-mysql)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name read again: the `Class.forName` part is not likely the source of the error, because you certainly have that class in classpath. Since Java 1.6 you don't need to to explictly load JDBC drivers, so getting the wrong (but existent) class will produce no harm. I repeat, _I know it's wrong_, but that's not the source of the error.

Comment: BTW you are not closing any of your resources (connection, statement).  Make sure your use try..finally < Java 7 or try-with-resources for Java => 7. A second note: you are vulnerable to sql-injection on this swing app. Use prepared statement (better yet use a SQL framework such as MyBatis or Spring JDBC)

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: I am aware of that, but it still doesn't make sense to load that class.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need following:

1. If you are working with MySQL ... you need MySQL's connectorJ and do following:

   ```
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   ```
2. When you run the above code make sure that the MySQL's connectorJ (which can be downloaded from MySQL website) is available on classpath so that it can actually be loaded otherwise you will hit class not found exception

Comment: Loading the driver with `Class.forName` is no longer necessary if the driver is JDBC 4.0 or higher. More likely the driver simply isn't on the classpath.

Comment: didnt know about the auto scanning in JDBC 4.0 ... I agree ... probably the driver is not found in classpath

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to that:
`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

And be sure that your jar is on the class path

Answer (score -1):

use `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in your `Class.forName`

> **CHANGE THIS**

`Class.forName("java.mysql.DriverManager");`

> **TO THIS**

`Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`