# How to sort a "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://[...]" exception when running a Java program in Cloud 9?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, cloud9-ide

I'm getting the error "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://[...]" when running a Java program on Cloud 9 which has the following ConnectionFactory class:

```
    import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectionFactory {
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:// [suppressed path, user and password details]");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

I know this is because I should install the MySQL  driver for Java in the server, but how do I do that in Cloud 9?

Comment: add mysql connector jar to build path

Comment: add Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); and mysql connector jar to build path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql)