# How to connect to mysql through jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to establish a connection to my mySQL database through a jdbc connection. I'm using a localhost connection at port 3006.

```
try{
   Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:mysql://localhost:3306/cupcakes", "kristoffer", "******");
   Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

   ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from cupcakes");
   while(myRs.next()){
       System.out.println("Cupcakes: " + myRs.getString("name"));
```

i get this error:
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    JDBC:mysql://localhost:3306/cupcakes
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at driverappformysql.DriverAppforMYSQL.main(DriverAppforMYSQL.java:21)

How can i assure that i'm connecting to the correct database, and how can i get the right url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No suitable driver found for 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146793/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306-mysql) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found

Comment: Try lowercase: `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cupcakes`. I've never seen it using uppercase `JDBC:` prefix, and it's likely case-sensitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify driver class..add this line before opening connection to database

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Try this

```
try{
   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
   Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("JDBC:mysql://localhost:3306/cupcakes", "kristoffer", "******");
   Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

   ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("Select * from cupcakes");
   while(myRs.next()){
       System.out.println("Cupcakes: " + myRs.getString("name"));
```

Further after successful connection..execute this query to get selected database

```
SELECT DATABASE() FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: I get a class not found exception, shall i create a new class?

Comment: Include mysql connector jar to your project, I mean to say the database driver jar

Comment: I can only find .zip or .tar files on the mysql website?

Comment: Correct...extract zip file this includes jar...download from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: Thank you. I added the jar file under libraries, however i still get a ClassNotFoundException?

Comment: Kindly paste complete code snippet..which is a part of connection i.e. try catch block

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165783/discussion-between-gaurav-genius-and-kristoffer-tolboll).

Answer (score 0):

Add

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Before opening connection.

Make sure you have added MySql to jdbc connector jar file which you can download on mysql's website.

Comment: Using `Class.forName` hasn't been necessary in a simple application like the one of the OP for at least a decade.