# (In Eclipse) JDBC Database access in servlet goes awry

Tags: java, database, servlets

I'm very new to web-application programming with Java.  I have two questions.

First:  I have a postgresql database.  I can access the database fine when doing it outside of a servlet (as a JUnit4 test).  However, when I try to access it via a servlet I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/comic_store
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at ilya.database.DBService.<clinit>(DBService.java:15)
at ilya.database.UserGateway.getUserByEmail(UserGateway.java:29)
at ilya.controller.Login.<init>(Login.java:12)
```

etc.
Why would this exception get thrown while accessing from a servlet, but not otherwise.

Second:  What is the preferred way of initializing a database connection in servlets?  Should I be creating a DataSource with web.xml?

Comment: Using Class.forName() solved the problem.  Using Tomcat 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5556664/844620) .  And [Apache's JNDI Datasources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) also helped.  Here's what worked: adding the driver jar to %CATALINA_HOME%/lib instead of WEB-INF/lib and then using Class.forName() to load the driver.  I tried excluding Class.forName() and got the same exception.  I also tried Class.forName() with the driver only in WEB-INF/lib, and that also didn't work.  As I said above, I'm running Tomcat 7 and jdk 1.6.0.