# No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://db4free.net:3306/partnerdb

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am trying to create a sample Spring application with JPA (MySQL DB) and Tomcat 7.0.28 under Mac OSX platform. I placed **mysql-connector-java-5.1.22** jar under **WEB-INF/lib** folder of the application. But when I start the app, I get error mentioned in the Title. I tried to put the same jar under **Tomcat lib** folder as well but getting the same error.

Same application when I deployed in Glassfish server with driver jar under **domain/lib/ext** folder, application works fine.

***Note:** Glassfish was also throwing the same error without putting the driver jar under **domain/lib/ext** folder.*

Answer (score 1):

Does this [How to fix: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" error when using pools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w) help ? Please check the second answer if you are connecting through program.

Comment: Anyone... Any idea please?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could give more details 1. Trace of the error. 2. How are you connecting to DB 3. Exact directory structure in TOMCAT where you are placing the JAR.