# What might be wrong with this JSP

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jsp

```
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop", "root", "");
```

XAMPP is hosting MySQL on 3306
I linked the mysql connect jar
ebookshop is the name of a DB

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAQBD.png

I have a user root wit no password

But I am getting a

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop

    ...
```

I have run other JSP and it works, I have a print statement just before the conn statement and it prints, one after that does not.

Thank you

Comment: Have you included the driver in `WEB-INF/lib` !!!

Comment: Where exactly did you put the mysql connector jar?

Comment: Looks like you're missing the MySQL driver .jar. Add it to your project and make sure it's added to the build.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/f8lMDjJ.png

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code :-

```
  try
    {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in Data base Driver:"+e);
    }
    try 
    {                   
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ebookshop", "root", ""; 
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,userName,pass);

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {           

        System.out.println("Error in database connection:"+e);


    }
```

First register your driver. Then you can use the url.

Comment: You, sir, are a gentlemen and a scholar.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) to your app's classpath. The most straight forward way to do that if you're running in a servlet container such as Tomcat or Jetty, would be to place the driver jar file in your app's `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Comment: @amiranthist: The driver may very well be in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder in your *project*, but it's likely not getting *deployed* along with your jsp files to your servlet container. If you're using your IDE to deploy, check that the libraries are part of the build package.

Comment: @amiranthist: Are you deploying with Eclipse? If so, go to Project > Properties and then Deployment Assembly. If the MySQL driver from `WEB-INF/lib` is not listed, add it.

Comment: That has not fixed the issue :/