# SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

Tags: java, mysql, linux, jdbc, sqlexception

I've inherited a project (and I have absolutly no experience of Java) and I'm rather stuck.

We have a server running redhat, which I needed to update one of the jar files. So I simply copied up the updated file and restarted the service for that file. However this process has worked on our other server I did that too but on this one it comes up with the below in the log file.

```
Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbanme
```

The jar files are uploaded to a folder in the root of the website and within that jar folder is a lib folder where mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar is located.

Does anyone know what I could be missing as I'm a newbie to linux aswell.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Post your code, we cannot guess what you written and tell you where the error is, we need some code

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w
if it didn't work post some code

Comment: You have not loaded JDBC Driver..

Answer (score 2):

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

This exception can have 2 causes:

1. The JDBC driver is not loaded at all.
2. URL does not match any of the loaded JDBC drivers.

Since the driver seems to be loaded , it look like that the URL is not valid on that machine:

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

Do you have mysql running and listening on port 3306 on that machine. Also make sure you hte schema dbname there.

Comment: I think your assumption that the driver is loaded is incorrect. A driver is only allowed to reject a URL based on the prefix, not on the fact that a machine is not running or running on a different port

Answer (score 0):

You need only set that:

```
[jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbanme]
```

instead of

```
[jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbanme]
```

Because java compiler default understand a port 3306, so no need to fill "3306" after "localhost:"