# Hibernate is not working under any AS

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a simple module with a few entities, persistence unit and all required hibernate dependencies. When I am trying to execute a simple read request using native HQL query from simple Java app everything is ok. But when I am trying to create a web app that uses this module and being deployed under any AS (GF, JBoss, Tomcat), I am getting an exception:

> ```
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://ec2-50-19-213-178.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/slave?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
>     at uselessmouths.listenerservice.service.TerminalsService.getAllTerminals(TerminalsService.java:27)
>     at uselessmouths.listenerservice.sevices.TerminalsGetterImpl.listAllTerminals(TerminalsGetterImpl.java:18)
>     at uselessmouths.listenerservice.sevices.TerminasPageController.handleRequestInternal(TerminasPageController.java:20)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
>     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:501)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
>     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
>     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
> ```

Could anyone recommend me something to check?

Comment: You must make sure that the MySQL JDBC driver is in your classpath.

Comment: How did you configure your persistence unit? Did you specify a jta-data-source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18131016/no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql)

Comment: jta-data-source, no, actually. What is it?