# One jar file for java class and MySQL driver

Tags: java, mysql, browser, applet

I want to put java class and MySQL driver in one jar file, beacuase now the applet works in NetBeans, but not in browser.

I have: Applet.class and mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar

and I want to put it in one jar. I do it like this:

```
jar cf Applet.jar Applet.class mysql-connector-java-5.1.27-bin.jar
```

But it still doesn't work in browser. I have an error: "no suitable driver for jdbc:mysql..."

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a browser applet that connects directly to a MySQL DB? What for? Do you know the security implications of this? Also this requires the box where you're running the applet to have JDBC MySQL driver installed.

Comment: You would need to unzip the jar first. Better try codebase applet attribute. Mind you would need to make the database not only for 'localhost' but open to the internet. Also look into signing your applet.

Comment: Yes, I have an applet directly connected with MySQL DB, but the connecton doesn't work there :/

Comment: I've signed my jar file

Comment: @user1950221 What m0skit0 meant with security implications: Are you aware that when the applet can access your database, then any application on the client can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

seems same as of answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w). Try putting the driver jar in the server lib folder.

Comment: is it right place to put it?I have WampServer  wamp->bin->apache->Apache2.4.4->lib