# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, connectivity

I have this Java program: `MySQLConnectExample.java`

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MySQLConnectExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn1 = null;
        Connection conn2 = null;
        Connection conn3 = null;

        try {
            String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "aa";

            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
            if (conn1 != null)
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");

            String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme?user=root&password=aa";
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url2);
            if (conn2 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test2");
            }

            String url3 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme";
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("user", "root");
            info.put("password", "aa");

            conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url3, info);
            if (conn3 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test3");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**I compile it like this:**

```
E:\java mysql code driver>javac MySQLConnectExample.java

E:\java mysql code driver>java -cp mysql-connector-java-3.0.11-stable-bin.jar;.
MySQLConnectExample
```

**I get this error:**

```
An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
aavikme
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
        at MySQLConnectExample.main(MySQLConnectExample.java:20)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have mysql running on your computer? Copying the data folder will not help, mysql server has to be running.

Comment: yes i have mysql running on my system

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5556664/632951

Answer (score 82):

Make sure you run this first:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

This forces the driver to register itself, so that Java knows how to handle those database connection strings.

For more information, see the [MySQL Connector reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html).

Comment: Its legacy code but it will most likely fix this problem because this is a very old driver. Downloading a more recent driver version will likely also make the problem go away without changing the code.

Comment: compile time error    class not found exception !!!

Comment: this is error while compiling E:\java mysql code driver>javac MySQLConnectExample.java MySQLConnectExample.java:16: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); ^ 1 error

Comment: Just a suggestion. The -cp argument on command line must point to the full path of the driver jar . Like -cp c:\jars\driverjar.jar;.

Comment: Even though that line is not required its very helpful to know if the driver is correctly loaded.

Comment: This is deprecated, please use "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" instead

Comment: `Class.forName` has not been needed for many years now. In modern Java, JDBC drivers are automatically loaded via [*Java Service Provider Interface*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface).

Answer (score 11):

You have to load `jdbc driver`. Consider below Code.

```
try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            // connect way #1
            String url1 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme";
            String user = "root";
            String password = "aa";

            conn1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url1, user, password);
            if (conn1 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test1");
            }

            // connect way #2
            String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme?user=root&password=aa";
            conn2 = DriverManager.getConnection(url2);
            if (conn2 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test2");
            }

            // connect way #3
            String url3 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/aavikme";
            Properties info = new Properties();
            info.put("user", "root");
            info.put("password", "aa");

            conn3 = DriverManager.getConnection(url3, info);
            if (conn3 != null) {
                System.out.println("Connected to the database test3");
            }
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("An error occurred. Maybe user/password is invalid");
            ex.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: compile time error    class not found exception !!!

Comment: see my modified answer.

Comment: what you have modified i don't see any change in code import

Comment: this is error while compiling                                E:\java mysql code driver>javac MySQLConnectExample.java
MySQLConnectExample.java:16: error: unreported exception ClassNotFoundException;
 must be caught or declared to be thrown
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             ^
1 error

Comment: http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ZwT6cx-fjH8/UyHhdxT3OeI/AAAAAAAAACU/S7GmSnHecSs/s1600/java+mysql.jpg THIS IS HOW I STORED MY DATA

Comment: I have added `ClassNotFoundException`. Try it.

Comment: on line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem, my code is below:

```
private Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Constant.MYSQL_URL, Constant.MYSQL_USER, Constant.MYSQL_PASSWORD);
private Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
```

I have not loaded the driver class, but it works locally, I can query the results from MySQL, however, it does not work when I deploy it to Tomcat, and the errors below occur:

```
No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://172.16.41.54:3306/eduCloud
```

so I loaded the driver class, as below, when I saw other answers posted:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

It works now! I don't know why it works well locally, I need your help, thank you so much!

Comment: I added the `Class.forName ... ` line just before establishing the connection.

Answer (score 5):

An example of retrieving data from a table having columns column1, column2 ,column3 column4, cloumn1 and 2 hold int values and column 3 and 4 hold `varchar(10)`

```
import java.sql.*; 
// need to import this as the STEP 1. Has the classes that you mentioned  
public class JDBCexample {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; 
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://LocalHost:3306/databaseNameHere"; 
    // DON'T PUT ANY SPACES IN BETWEEN and give the name of the database (case insensitive) 

    // database credentials
    static final String USER = "root";
    // usually when you install MySQL, it logs in as root 
    static final String PASS = "";
    // and the default password is blank

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;

        try {
    // registering the driver__STEP 2
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
    // returns a Class object of com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    // (forName(""); initializes the class passed to it as String) i.e initializing the
    // "suitable" driver
            System.out.println("connecting to the database");
    // opening a connection__STEP 3
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
    // executing a query__STEP 4 
            System.out.println("creating a statement..");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
    // creating an object to create statements in SQL
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT column1, cloumn2, column3, column4 from jdbcTest;";
    // this is what you would have typed in CLI for MySQL
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    // executing the query__STEP 5 (and retrieving the results in an object of ResultSet)
    // extracting data from result set
            while(rs.next()){
    // retrieve by column name
                int value1 = rs.getInt("column1");
                int value2 = rs.getInt("column2");
                String value3 = rs.getString("column3");
                String value4 = rs.getString("columnm4");
    // displaying values:
                System.out.println("column1 "+ value1);
                System.out.println("column2 "+ value2);
                System.out.println("column3 "+ value3);
                System.out.println("column4 "+ value4);

            }
    // cleaning up__STEP 6
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
    //  handle sql exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception for class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{  
    //closing the resources..STEP 7
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("good bye");
    }
}
```

Comment: on line `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 4):

You might have not copied the `MySQL connector/J` jar file into the lib folder and then this file has to be there in the classpath.

If you have not done so, please let me know I shall elaborate the answer

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are missing `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

This is what you are missing to have everything working.

Answer (score 3):

All of the answers here use the `Class.forName("my.vandor.Driver");` line to load the driver.

As an (better) alternative you can use the `DriverManager` helper class which provides you with a handful of methods to handle your JDBC driver/s.

You might want to

1. Use `DriverManager.registerDriver(driverObject);` to register your driver to it's list of drivers

> Registers the given driver with the DriverManager. A newly-loaded driver class should call the method registerDriver to make itself known to the DriverManager. If the driver is currently registered, no action is taken

2. Use `DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driverObject);` to remove it.

> Removes the specified driver from the DriverManager's list of registered drivers.

Example:

```
Driver driver = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
DriverManager.registerDriver(driver);
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
// ... 
// and when you don't need anything else from the driver
DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
```

or better yet, use a [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html)

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem, just verify the port where your Mysql server is running, that will solve the problem

For example, my code was:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080/bddventas","root","");
```

i change the string to

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bddventas","root","");
```

and voila!!, this workd because my server was running on that port

Hope this help

Comment: by default mysql listen to port 3306

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<dbname>";
String user = "<username>";
String password = "<password>";
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
```