# Database doesn't work on netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans, netbeans-8

My database does not work, I get and error that I pasted after the code:

```
    try {

        String url = "jdbc:derby:test";
        String name = "root";
        String password = "123";
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
        Statement state = con.createStatement();
        String query = "INSERT INTO APP.UNTITLED (id , name , password ) VALUES (1, 'Anas','123456789')";
        state.execute(query);

    }
    catch (SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }  
}
```

this is the error that appears:

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby:test
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
    at testdatabase.TestDatabase.main(TestDatabase.java:25)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306

Comment: Have you seen my answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `Class.forName` to look for the classpath to find suitable driver.

```
try {
 ...
 Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance(); 
 Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, name, password);
 Statement state = con.createStatement();
 ...
 }    

 catch (....
```

Don't forget to add library to your project

**java DB Driver**

with following jar files.

**derby.jar

derbyclient.jar

derbynet.jar**