# mysql connection with java.... i'm very confusing

Tags: java, mysql

I want to connect to mysql in java. So i found sample, and executed that. it works very well. So, to use this sample in my program, i make the one class. however, when i connected to db, it threw error. But, in the sample, it still works well. i don't know why it threw error. help me.

This is sample code.

```html
public class Test {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
   Connection con = null;

   con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readability",
     "root", "root");
        } catch (SQLException sqex) {
   System.out.println("SQLException: " + sqex.getMessage());
   System.out.println("SQLState: " + sqex.getSQLState());
  }
 }
}
```

This is a part of my db class.

```html
public class DBConnector {
 private static DBConnector dbConnector;
 private Connection connect = null;
 private Statement statement = null;
 private ResultSet resultSet = null;
 private String id = "root";
 private String password = "root";

 public void createConnection() {
  if (connect == null) {
   try {
    connect =  DriverManager
                           .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readability",
          "root", "root");
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
 }
    ......
}
```

This is error message.

```html
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/readability
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at kr.ac.jbnu.ssel.readability.repository.DBConnector.createConnection(DBConnector.java:26)
 at kr.ac.jbnu.ssel.readability.ui.views.InstantFeedbackView.createPartControl(InstantFeedbackView.java:50)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView.createPartControl(CompatibilityView.java:143)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:341)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:54)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:966)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:931)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:151)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:375)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:294)
 at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:162)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:74)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:56)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:129)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:536)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:520)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ElementReferenceRenderer.createWidget(ElementReferenceRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:975)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:651)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.StackRenderer.showTab(StackRenderer.java:1317)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveRenderer.processContents(PerspectiveRenderer.java:49)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.showTab(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.LazyStackRenderer.postProcess(LazyStackRenderer.java:103)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.PerspectiveStackRenderer.postProcess(PerspectiveStackRenderer.java:63)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:669)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SashRenderer.processContents(SashRenderer.java:142)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.SWTPartRenderer.processContents(SWTPartRenderer.java:70)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.WBWRenderer.processContents(WBWRenderer.java:725)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:665)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:757)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$0(PartRenderingEngine.java:728)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$2.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:722)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:706)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1059)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
 at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
 at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
 at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
 at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
 at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
 at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

**ADD**

I already add library in my project.
This is sample.
[image]

This is my project.

[image]

Comment: It would seem that you are missing the [driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Comment: It has told you, no driver! So you need load mysql driver first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22384781/3511123

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306)

Comment: I added current reference in my project. i already add library in my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this before calling getConnection() :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

and mysql-connector-java-{version}-bin.jar in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You need Class.forName() before the DriverManager.getConnection line.

Comment: Actually not, the driver has to be in your classpath only. It's a Java 6/JDBC 4.0 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Add library MYSQLJDBC driver ,right click on libraries ,then add library

Answer (score 0):

load mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar in $CATALINA_HOME/lib