# Why am I getting java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found when the url is correct and driver is present?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am trying the following code to make connection with my database online, hosted on ElephantSQL.

```java
private static Connection getConnection() {

        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Jar not found "+e.getMessage());
        }

        //dbUrl is given this way
        String dbUrl = "jdbc:postgres://database:password@manny.db.elephantsql.com:5432/database";

        String username = "database";
        String password = "password";

        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl,username,password);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

But I am getting the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for < url >

I tried all the things from the similar questions which I found here
[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384710/java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost3306)
and
[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1911253/the-infamous-java-sql-sqlexception-no-suitable-driver-found).

But nothing worked and I am stuck. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: No other logs? Could you please post a bit more the exception you got ?

Comment: Unrelated, but: you don't need `Class.forName()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html) the URL for Postgres must be structured like this:

```
jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database
```

The prefix `jdbc:postgres` needs to be `jdbc:postgresql` and the part `database:password@manny.db.elephantsql.com:5432` in your URL is wrong. It's hard to tell what exactly the hostname is, but I guess you need to use:

```
jdbc:postgresql://manny.db.elephantsql.com:5432/database
```

Comment: The error remains same, it still is saying no suitable driver found for < changed url, without database:password >

Comment: @Panda: I overlooked another error in your URL. It needs to be `postgresql` not `postgres` in the prefix.

Comment: Thank you, I also couldn't spot that :)

Answer (score -1):

It seems that your driver jar file is not in classpath.

One of the option is put driver jar file in lib directory of your project and add jar file in classpath ( or buildpath in eclipse )

you can download dirver file from given URL
https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Comment: That would throw a ClassNotFoundException