# what is the correct connection string for connecting to sql server database via jdbc

Tags: java, selenium, jdbc, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to parameterize gmail login script, for which I am trying to fetch data from database(sql server), but when I run the code am getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
>   found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/hrm

The connection string that I am passing is as follows:

```
Connection cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost/hrm","sa","a1");
```

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" error when using pools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w)

Answer (score 1):

Was your jdbc driver correctly added to the build path?
If that is not the problem you can add Class.forName(yourDriver);  in your code

Hope that helps

Comment: `Class.forName()` hasn't been necessary to load JDBC drivers since Java 5.  If you are using Java6+ and JDBC 4+ it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add required JDBC Driver or jar.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx

If you provided jar in build path, please provide more code to help you.

Thanks