# Cpanel: No suitable driver found for localhost

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, cpanel

I just purchased a hosting service and added my J2EE web project via cpanel and successfully created a database in MySQL. But I am facing a problem in creating a JDBC connection with cpanel. It says "*No suitable driver found for localhost*". I guess cpanel is not able to detect the MySQL J connector in `web-inf/lib` - but why???
Is their something else to be done to run it? I am new to cpanel. Here is my connection class

```
public class DbConnection {


    private static Connection connection;
    public static Connection getConnection()
    {
        return connection;
    }
    static
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("localhost","abcas","*******");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a .JAR in your `classpath` that **has** `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in it?

Comment: yes i have  'mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar' in web-inf/lib/ folder

Comment: One more thing this application is working fine on my eclipse with mysql @Tersosauros

Comment: And that library version matches your MySQL version? and that path is on the `classpath` being used by your J2EE environment? ...*and* MySQL is definitely running on localhost on the default port?

Comment: yess because there is no issue with Class.forname(**) like it doesn't says classnotfoundexception or something like that. Issue is with DriverManager.getConnection(**)

Comment: Are you specifying a conection string anywhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix: "No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname" error when using pools?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w)

Comment: no I have hardcoded the hostname username and password in the code itself. You can see from the code @Tersosauros

Comment: Lot of 3rd party hosting disallow this construct (supplying JDBC driver via webapp instead of via server) because it's subject to memory leaks. If the MySQL database is also hosted by the same hosting, then usually they already offer a server-configured connection pooled `DataSource` which you should grab from JNDI via e.g. `@Resource`. Consult their documentation/help for detail as to the JNDI name. By the way, "J2EE" died a decade ago and is since renamed to Java EE. I'm not sure which resources you're using to learn Java EE, but you need to make absolutely sure they are up to date.