# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:orcale:thin:@localhost:1521:xe'

Tags: java, spring-orm

I am writing a program based on CURD operation based on Spring-orm module.

```
//dao class
//StudentDAO.java
package com.nt.dao;

import com.nt.domains.StudentInfo;

public interface StudentDAO {
public StudentInfo getStudentInfo(int sid);
}
//StudentInfo.java
package com.nt.dao;

import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate;

import com.nt.domains.StudentInfo;

public class StudnetInfoImpl implements StudentDAO {
//bean
    private HibernateTemplate htemplate;



    public void setHtemplate(HibernateTemplate htemplate) {
        this.htemplate = htemplate;
    }



    @Override
    public StudentInfo getStudentInfo(int sid) {
        StudentInfo studentInfo=null;
        studentInfo=(StudentInfo)htemplate.save(sid);
        return studentInfo;
    }

}

//service class
//studentservice.java
package com.nt.service;

import com.nt.domains.StudentInfo;

public interface StudentService {
public StudentInfo getStudentDetails(int sid);
}
//studentserviceimpl.java
package com.nt.service;

import com.nt.dao.StudentDAO;
import com.nt.domains.StudentInfo;

public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
//beans
    private StudentDAO dao;
//setters

    public void setDao(StudentDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }

//override method
    @Override
    public StudentInfo getStudentDetails(int sid) {
        StudentInfo info=null;
        info=dao.getStudentInfo(sid);
        return info;
    }
```

Spring configuration file

```
//service-bean.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="service" class="com.nt.service.StudentServiceImpl">
<property name="dao" ref="dao"></property>
</bean>
</bean
//persistance-bean.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="dbcp" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <property name="url" value="jdbc:orcale:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
      <property name="username" value="system"/>
         <property name="password" value="jinibini123"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sesfact" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
      <property name="dataSource"  ref="dbcp"/>
      <property name="annotatedClasses">
          <list>
               <value>com.nt.domains.StudentInfo</value>
          </list>
     </property>
     <property name="hibernateProperties">
       <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
      </props>
   </property>
</bean>
<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sesfact"/>
</bean>
<bean id="dao" class="com.nt.dao.StudnetInfoImpl">
  <property name="htemplate" ref="template"/>
</bean>
</beans>
//applicationcontext.xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<import resource="persistance-beans.xml"/>
<import resource="service-beans.xml"/>
</beans>
```

```java
//clientapplicatrion
//CURDTet.java
package com.nt.test;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.nt.service.StudentService;

public class CURDTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create IOC
        ApplicationContext ctx=null;
        StudentService service=null;
        ctx=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/nt/cfgs/applicationcontext.xml");
        service=ctx.getBean("service",StudentService.class);
        //invoke methods
        System.out.println("101 table records:"+service.getStudentDetails(101));
//close IOC
        ((AbstractApplicationContext) ctx).close();
    }

}
```

When I'm trying to run this program on Tomcat 8.0 server I am getting the following exception. Can you please help me how to proceed further...

```
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:47 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6b179d: startup date [Fri Sep 01 12:17:47 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:47 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/nt/cfgs/applicationcontext.xml]
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/nt/cfgs/persistance-beans.xml]
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/nt/cfgs/service-beans.xml]
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.10.Final}
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator initiateService
WARN: HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:orcale:thin:@localhost:1521:xe'
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:48 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.LobCreatorBuilderImpl makeLobCreatorBuilder
INFO: HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
Sep 01, 2017 12:17:49 PM org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper executeIdTableCreationStatements
ERROR: Unable obtain JDBC Connection
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver' for connect URL 'jdbc:orcale:thin:@localhost:1521:xe'
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1150)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:880)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$1.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:419)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.IdTableHelper.executeIdTableCreationStatements(IdTableHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.global.GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.finishPreparation(GlobalTemporaryTableBulkIdStrategy.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.prepare(AbstractMultiTableBulkIdStrategyImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:511)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:495)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.nt.test.CURDTest.main(CURDTest.java:15)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1143)
    ... 27 more

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.checkWriteOperationAllowed(HibernateTemplate.java:1165)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate$12.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:359)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:326)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate.save(HibernateTemplate.java:640)
    at com.nt.dao.StudnetInfoImpl.getStudentInfo(StudnetInfoImpl.java:22)
    at com.nt.service.StudentServiceImpl.getStudentDetails(StudentServiceImpl.java:19)
    at com.nt.test.CURDTest.main(CURDTest.java:18)
```

Comment: First thing which I see is that you have a typo in JDBC connection string: `orcale` instead of `oracle`. Try fixing that first.

Comment: If Igor's comment didn't help, check [e.g. this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w) or any other of the many questions here about the same topic if one of the many answers there do fit.