# Table not found error in eclipse IDE, what to do?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I recently started working on JDBC and I got an Error as Table not found

```
Table TRIAL not found; SQL statement:
insert into trial values(1,'hello') [42102-73]
```

Here is my code, also I have already created a table in h2 DB

```
package trial1;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Customer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test","Aziz", "password");
            Statement st = conn.createStatement();
            String str = "insert into trial values(1,'hello')";
                    st.execute(str);
            System.out.println("Succes");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As the error tells you, there is no table called `TRIAL` in your database. Make sure the table exists.

Comment: now i'm getting another error as : ava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for dbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
 at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
 at trial1.Customer.main(Customer.java:12)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w

Comment: That error in your comments is because your URL is wrong, it needs to start with `jdbc`, not with `dbc`.

Comment: Thankyou very much. So silly of me after correcting the spell the program worked for me.