# Is there any nzjdbc.jar which is compatible with Mac

Tags: netezza

I am trying to connect to Netteza Database through Dbeaver. I have the .jar file, but when i try to connect I get the following error.

No suitable driver found for jdbc:netezza://**.***.***.***:5480/DM_BEM

I am using MacBook pro. Kindly help where can I find correct jdbc driver or any other way to connect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w Refer 2nd/3rd answer

Answer (score 0):

The Netezza jdbc driver can be used on Mac. One way to test out to make sure that you are able to connect is to use the test functionality in the  jdbc driver itself.

```sh
CLASSPATH=/path/to/driver  # $CLASSPATH/nzjdbc3.jar should exist
java -jar $CLASSPATH/nzjdbc3.jar  -t --host <host> -u <user> -db system
```

This will test out that the connection is working and there are no other environmental issues. At that point, check to make DBbeaver has found the jdbc jar file

[Click "Add File" and then "Find Class"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bCdj.png)

Click on Add File and then Find class to make sure Netezza jdbc driver and class is found correctly.

Comment: I have done Add File and Find Class..... yet I couldn't get connected.

Comment: @Tulip could you elaborate on what error you see? Did the "Add File" and "Find Class" succeed.