# Error whiling to fetch data from a MySQL database using jstl in a maven project

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jstl

the same code is working perfectly fine in another non-maven project

[errors-img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4W2J.png)
[maven dependencies-img link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UvXT.png)

```
<sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/uu" user="root" password="#Akshpnwr123#"/>

<sql:query var="rs" dataSource="${db}">select * from students</sql:query>

<c:forEach items="${rs.rows}" var="student">

    ${student.id} : ${student.s_name} : ${student.password} : ${student.s_course} <br>

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556664/how-to-fix-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbcmysql-localhost-dbname-error-w) post ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @VivekJain i added an image link.

Comment: @Swati the same code is working perfectly fine in another project which is not maven based

Comment: Please don't use images to show your code. Just copy and past it here respecting formatting.

Comment: Just a rule of thumb: Making database connections directly in the JSP file rather than using servlets is a *horrible* practice.