# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, jdbc, sqlexception

I am working on a web application where I am creating MSSQLSERVER 2008
database dynamically.

But it's giving me

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master
```

**My code is:**

```
String dbName = "db1";
try {
    String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master";
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                 url,
                 "sa",
                 "roshan14121987");

    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    String sqlquery = "CREATE Database \"" + dbName + "\"; ";
    statement.executeUpdate(sqlquery);
    statement.close();

    connection.close();

} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); 
}
```

I have added sqljdbc4.jar in lib. I have tried it on both NetBeans (with GlassFish and Tomcat Server) and Eclipse IDE(Tomcat Server).

On the other hand I have tried this with simple desktop application, it's working fine on both IDEs. With sqljdbc4.jar added in lib.

Comment: Try adding the .JAR to the `lib\ ` folder of tomcat.

Comment: Yes i have added already in lib...

Comment: Try: `Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=master;user=sa;password=roshan14121987");`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Before calling `DriverManager.getConnection()` you will have to load the SQLServer JDBC driver. You can do `Class.forName("xxxx");` where xxxx is the appropriate driver class (fully qualified name with package prefix).

EDIT: Do this `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` to load the driver. Refer [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx) for more.

Comment: +1 Nice catch, this could be it!

Comment: @Bimalesh yes it working with Class.forName("xxxx"), but i confused why it is working without Class.forName("xxxx") when i used this same code in simple java class.

Comment: @Aniket your code must be referring/loading the driver somewhere, not necessarily in your code, but may be some initialization routine somewhere else. Pls dig deeper.

Comment: In my experience the Class.forName call was not needed for stand-alone Java applications, but I needed to add it when I used the same code in a Tomcat web application.

Comment: I find a strange behavior with my application. I could connect to SQL without Class.for..... line but when I run it as a Jar I could not connect to SQL. What must have happened?

Comment: @manikantanvsr that is due to changes in modern versions of java runtime using service providers mechanism https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider . Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220724/class-fornamejdbc-driver-no-longer-needed You can implement a services/META-INF for this in your jar package.

Answer (score 2):

Is `sqljdbc4.jar` in your war file under WEB-INF/lib. This is the alternate location to $CATALINA_HOME/lib and recommended to keep your web application self-contained. Further, if you should ever need to change servers, you need only drop the war into your webapps directory.

You might also need a Class.forName([database class]).newInstance, but that [isn't necessary using a JDBC 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver) driver. Good luck and if you have further problems, do leave a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The error happen in the runtime on Tomcat Server,right? I think you need to make sure your sqljdbc4.jar deploy the in the Server.