# Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER) no longer needed?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I've read here on SO that since java 6 you no longer need to register JDBC Driver using:

```
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
```

because DriverManager uses the path located in system property **"jdbc.drivers"**
to retrieve the correct driver.

But when I do the followng:

```
System.out.print(System.getProperty("jdbc.drivers"));
```

`null` gets printed.

Do you have any clue why my app works correctly ?? ;)

Comment: It's all explained in the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That has nothing to do with that system property. Java6 (and JDBC4) introduced a concept known as "[service provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#Service%20Provider)" where implementations of known interface can be detected by the JVM during startup. A driver that is compliant with that will be registered by the DriverManager automatically. That's why `Class.forName()` is no longer necessary - but only if the driver supports that.

The service registration is initiated if there is a `services` directory in the driver's jar file inside the META-INF directory. That directory needs to contain a text file with the name of the interface that is implemented in the case of a JDBC driver that is `java.sql.Driver` containing the implementing class.

Comment: That means that all I have to do is indicate my JDBC jar implementation , right ? what if I indicate more JDBC implementation ?

Comment: @user986437 Yes, adding a JDBC 4 driver on the classpath is enough. I haven't tried with multiple drivers, but I guess the correct one will be picked dependent on the URL provided (every driver supports a different URL).

Comment: It's JDBC 4 not JDBC 3, which introduced that mechanim; http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/package-summary.html#package.description

Comment: @user986437 Multiple JDBC implementations are not a problem, as long as they use a different JDBC-protocol url-prefix (eg jdbc:mysql, jdbc:firebirdsql, jdbc:postgresql etc).

Answer (score 3):

From the Javadocs of `DriverManager`:

> As part of its initialization, the `DriverManager` class will attempt to load the driver classes referenced in the "jdbc.drivers" system property. This allows a user to customize the JDBC Drivers used by their applications. For example in your ~/.hotjava/properties file you might specify:
>
> ```
> jdbc.drivers=foo.bah.Driver:wombat.sql.Driver:bad.taste.ourDriver
> ```

This means that the system property need not be specified (as it says `DriverManager` will *attempt*). There is another mechanism through which drivers are automatically loaded, which relies on [service loading](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) since Java 6:

> The `DriverManager` methods `getConnection` and `getDrivers` have been enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver.

Almost all JDBC drivers now conform to this requirement. Note that `DriverManager` does not internally fill the `jdbc.drivers` property, so it's still null.

Comment: You shouldn't call the `registerDriver` method yourself, it is intended to be called by the JDBC driver implementation itself when it is loaded. The only real exception is if you use a driver that doesn't register itself (and almost all JDBC drivers register themselves when loaded, maybe with the exception of special-purpose (not mainstream) drivers).

Comment: "This means that the system property should be specified. " - That is not correct if using a JDBC 4 driver, and the behavior described in the question suggests that he/she is using a JDBC 4 driver.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown that was indeed badly formulated. It was more like the system property would have to be specified for it to print as not null -- It's corrected now.