# Connect SQL Server database from Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I need to Connect the SQL Server 2008 from the Java.

Here is my code:

```
public class Sql {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");


         public static void main(String[] args){
                // Neue DB und los geht's :)
                DB db = new DB();
                db.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://Data Source=500.20.13.1;InitialCatalog=LicenceManagement;UseID=XXXXX;Password=YYYY");
            }
    }

    class DB{

        public void dbConnect(  String db_connect_string, 
                                String db_userid, 
                                String db_password){
            try{
            Class.forName( "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" );
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                db_connect_string, 
                            db_userid, 
                            db_password);
                System.out.println( "connected" );
            }
            catch( Exception e ){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

But the connection isn't established, and I get the following error:

> ERR :No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver://Data
>   Source=500.20.13.1;InitialCatalog=LicenceManagement;UseID=XXXXX;Password=YYYY"

Comment: Do you have SQL Server jdbc driver on path?

Comment: driver is missing, include that - No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Comment: Have you downloaded and added SQL Server JDBC driver to your 
classpath? And it should be UserId not UseId. Connection string looks incorrect too

Comment: You have the wrong URL format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-2017#making-a-simple-connection-to-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for jdbc Driver for MSSQL:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to find a driver like @Benedikt Geltenpoth said above (or below).

Secondly include your driver in your classpath, after you've download it.

Third From Java 1.6 upward, you dont need to register the driver class anymore
see (in theorie) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28220844/755401). the driver is JDBC type 4

Lastly A simple pattern for your connection would be  `jdbc:sqlserver://server:port;DatabaseName=dbname` plus your url parameters

```
    public class Sql {

             public static void main(String[] args){
                    // Neue DB und los geht's :)
                    DB db = new DB();
                    int yourPort = 1433;
                    String initialCatalog = "LicenceManagement";
                    String userId = "userOne";
                    String password= "passwordOne";
db.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://"+500.20.13.1+":"+yourPort+";DatabaseName="+initialCatalog,userId,password);
                }
        }

        class DB{

            public void dbConnect(  String db_connect_string, 
                                    String db_userid, 
                                    String db_password){
                try{
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                    db_connect_string, 
                                db_userid, 
                                db_password);
                    System.out.println( "connected" );
                }
                catch( SQLException e ){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
```