# Not able to insert million records from csv file to MySql database

Tags: java, mysql, apache-commons-csv

So I wanted to read per say 100 lines and print it and it should be happening for every 100 lines and I don't know where to insert that code. The CSV file with one million records isn't getting inserted into the DB as only few thousand are getting inserted.

```
String csvFilePath = "C:\\Student1.csv";
try {
    BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\File12\\Student1.csv"));
    CSVParser records = CSVParser.parse(lineReader, CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
    System.out.println(records.size);
    ArrayList<TestSql> students = new ArrayList<TestSql>();
    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        TestSql testsql = new TestSql();
        testsql.setDate(record.get(0));
        testsql.setName(record.get(1));
        testsql.setGender(record.get(2));

        students.add(testsql);
    }
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    Connection con = dbconnection();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO test12(DOB, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (TestSql record : students) {
        statement.setString(1, record.getDate());
        statement.setString(2, record.getName());
        statement.setString(3, record.getGender());
        statement.addBatch();
    }
    statement.executeBatch();
    con.commit();
    con.close();

} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

```
public static Connection dbconnection() {
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newschema1", "root", "12345");
        System.out.println("connection sucessfull");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Comment: No like that works but million reecords is too much to read. So i wanted to read like 100 or 1000 records from the csv file and print it

Comment: Why don't you simply use mysql's built-in load data statement for importing csv files?

Comment: (Jdbc) connection (timeout) can be an issue (on big loads). No stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert records from the CSV file into the database table in batches of 100, then you need a counter. In the below code I use a variable `count`. Whenever it reaches 100, the code inserts those 100 rows and resets the `count` variable.

Note: More explanations after the code.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVRecord;

public class CsvParse {
    private static final int  LIMIT = 100;

    public static Connection dbConnection() throws SQLException {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/newschema1",
                                                            "root",
                                                            "12345");
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        return connection;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader lineReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\File12\\Student1.csv"))) {
            CSVParser records = CSVParser.parse(lineReader,
                                                CSVFormat.EXCEL.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withIgnoreHeaderCase().withTrim());
            String sql = "INSERT INTO test12(DOB, NAME, GENDER) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
            Connection con = dbConnection();
            PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql); 
            int count = 0;
            for (CSVRecord record : records) {
                count++;
                if (count > LIMIT) {
                    count = 1;
                    statement.executeBatch();
                    con.commit();
                    statement.clearBatch();
                }
                statement.setString(1, record.get(0));
                statement.setString(2, record.get(1));
                statement.setString(3, record.get(2));
                statement.addBatch();
            }
            // Insert last batch that may be less than LIMIT.
            statement.executeBatch();
            con.commit();
            con.close();
            records.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In method `dbConnection()`, I removed `Class.forName()` since it is [no longer needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220724/class-fornamejdbc-driver-no-longer-needed). I also changed the exception handling. If the method fails to obtain a database connection then there's not much point in continuing since you won't be able to insert anything into the database and that's the whole point of the program. So catching the `SQLException` in method `dbConnection()` and printing the stack trace means that when you try to create a `PreparedStatement`, you will get a `NullPointerExcetion` since `con` will be null.

In method `main` I use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) when creating `lineReader`.

I don't see the reason for class `TestSql`. You can simply set the `PreparedStatement` parameters directly from the CSV record.

Since Java 7 there is [multi-catch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html) so no need for a separate `catch` block for each exception when each `catch` block simply prints the stack trace.