# How to show a dialog box if id is not present in the MySQL database

Tags: swing, jdbc

I can update data properly using Java Swing and MySQL. If `id` is present in the database `JOptionPane` shows a dialog box that *Updated data Succesfully* and even `id` is not present in the database `JOtionPane` shows the same dialog box. How to solve that?

```java
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventoryms", "root", "");
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String query = "update inventory set name = '"+txtName.getText()+"', price = '"+txtPrice.getText()+"', category = '"+comboCat.getSelectedItem().toString()+"' where id = '"+txtId.getText()+"' ";
        stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Data updated successfully!!");
        conn.close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error is: " + ex);
    }
}
```

Show the same dialog box that updated data successfully.

Comment: `stmt.executeUpdate(query);` returns an `int`. Its value will be zero if update was not successful and `1` (or more) in case the `id` was a match. So, you can use the returned value to check and show appropriate message in the dialog window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75026745/how-to-show-a-dialog-box-if-id-is-not-present-in-the-mysql-database#comment132399686_75026745), by @prasad_, to your question, is the answer. Method [executeUpdate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) returns the number of rows affected by your UPDATE statement. Note that it is **not** an error if the UPDATE statement does not update any rows.

Apart from that, note the following:

- Since Java 6, you no longer need to explicitly load the JDBC driver class via [Class.forName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220724/class-fornamejdbc-driver-no-longer-needed).
- You should use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) (rather than `Statement`).
- You should also close the `PreparedStatement` and the `Connection` which you can do via [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).
- You can use [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/text-blocks/index.html) to make your SQL more readable.
- You should catch the exception that the method throws which, in your case, is `SQLException` and you should print the stack trace in order to help find the cause of the exception.
- Note that the *message* displayed by [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) can be any object and does not have to be a string.

```java
private void btnUpdateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String query = """
    update inventory
       set name = ?
          ,price = ?
          ,category = ?
     where id = ?
    """;
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/inventoryms", "root", "");
         PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query)) {
        stmt.setString(1, txtName.getText());
        stmt.setString(2, txtPrice.getText());
        stmt.setString(3, comboCat.getSelectedItem().toString());
        stmt.setString(4, txtId.getText());
        int count = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        String msg = count > 0 ? "Data updated successfully!!" : "No changes.";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        ex.printStackTrace(pw);
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(sw.toString());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, scrollPane, "ERROR", JOptionPane. ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Refer to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int)) of `JOptionPane`.