# jdbc connection "alternative to Class.forname for driver loading"

Tags: jdbc

can we use anything else instead of `Class.forName()` for loading a driver for jdbc connectivity
i.e is first step of jdbc connection?

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JDBC Class.forName vs DriverManager.registerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver)

Answer (score 2):

> can we use anything else instead of "Class.forname" for loading a driver for jdbc connectivity i.e is first step of jdbc connection?

You haven't even needed that [since JDBC 4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html). Just call `DriverManager.getConnection()` with an appropriate URL.

Answer (score 0):

Just import `java.sql.Driver` and invoke `DriverManager.getConnecion()` to establish a database connection. You don't really need to call `Call.forName()` these days (java7).