# How to increment my primary key by selecting in java with mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have the code to select `msg_id` and increment it from my database name final client from table msg but when I run, it says that `Failed to Select from DBjava.sql.SQLException: Column 'msg_id' not found`

```
int maxid;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/finalclient","root","");

    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("select *from msgs order by msg_id desc");
    ResultSet r1=st.executeQuery();

    maxid = r1.getInt("msg_id") + 1;

    System.out.println(r1.getInt("msg_id"));
    System.out.println(maxid);                  
}
catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Failed to Select from DB"+e);
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: really is there a column named msg_id

Comment: I tried to clean up your question, but I have absolutely no idea what "increment it from my database name final client from table msg" is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 0):

Initially the resultset's cursor is positioned before the first row. You need to move the cursor to the first record before you can get any values:

```
ResultSet r1 = st.executeQuery();
r1.first(); // or r1.next()
maxid = r1.getInt("msg_id") + 1;
```

---

On a slightly different note, your query is fairly inefficient. Probably would be better to do:

```
SELECT MAX(msg_id) as max_id FROM msgs
```

Answer (score 0):

### Your attempt is absolutely not the correct idiom to generate numeric ids

What you are doing is a very naive attempt and will not work with more than one client or more than one thread accessing the database.

Primary keys should be immutable, as in you can't change them once they are created, otherwise data corruption becomes rampant as foreign keys become orphans for example.

#### Correct Idiom

1. Use an [auto-increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) column for your primary key.
2. Learn SQL properly and learn to use more efficient SQL statement: `SELECT MAX(msg_id) as maxid FROM MSG` as in the example below, but an auto-increment key is the correct way.
3. There is no reason to use a `PreparedStatement` if there are no parameters you need to pass in.
4. Don't use 10 year old books, tutorials or examples from the web that do things like your example.

That said, you are very close, here is what your code should look like to fix your code that is posted, but keep in mind **this is the wrong to do what you are trying to accomplish**:

#### [Q26227752.java](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q26227752.java)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Q26227752
{
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            final Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/finalclient", "root", "");
            try
            {
                final Statement ps = cn.createStatement();
                try
                {
                    final ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(msg_id) as maxid FROM msgs");
                    try
                    {
                        // always check to see if something was actually returned
                        if (rs.next())
                        {
                            final int maxid = rs.getInt("maxid");
                            System.out.format("maxid = %d\n", maxid);
                            System.out.format("nextid = %d\n", maxid + 1);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new SQLException("No rows returned for \"SELECT MAX(msg_id) FROM msgs\"");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (final SQLException e)
                    {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        try { rs.close(); } catch (final SQLException e) { System.err.print(e.getMessage()); }
                    }
                }
                catch (final SQLException e)
                {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    try { ps.close(); } catch (final SQLException e) { System.err.print(e.getMessage()); }
                }
            }
            catch (final SQLException e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            finally
            {
                try { cn.close(); } catch (final SQLException e) { System.err.print(e.getMessage()); }
            }
        }
        catch (final SQLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes:

#### As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5484254/177800).

> The DriverManager methods getConnection and getDrivers have been
>   enhanced to support the Java Standard Edition Service Provider
>   mechanism. JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file
>   META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the
>   JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load
>   the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file
>   would contain the entry:
>
> my.sql.Driver Applications no longer need to explicitly load JDBC
>   drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load
>   JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without
>   modification.

#### Always close resources correctly:

You **MUST** always get in a habit of the hierarchy of `try/catch/finally` blocks when dealing with external resources like database connections, statements and what not. Java 7+ has enhanced syntactic sugary ways of dealing with them, but the principal is the same.

#### Use a proper primary key generator supported by your RDBMS

```
CREATE TABLE msgs
(
  msg_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
```

#### SELECT * is never correct:

`SELECT *` is a very lazy and dangerous way to write SQL `SELECT` statements.

Especially if you use column numbers instead of names, if the table changes order of the columns and the types are the same you will silently corrupt your data.

Only selecting the columns you need is explicit, and explicit is always better than implicit!

It is also inefficient if there are lots of columns that are large and you don't need.

As always complete examples are available at [my GitHub repository of answers and example code](https://github.com/jarrodhroberson/Stack-Overflow).

Comment: This answer would be a lot easier to understand if you made it _use_ the try-with-resources feature of Java 7 that you referenced.  That's _a lot_ of nested try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

In mysql primary key should use autoincrement column where when you insert in table the it is automatically taken care of incrementing that column by 1  and  there is no need to get max and increment by one and mysql does it for you.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Answer (score 0):

- You can set `msg_id` as a auto increment in DB. Then no need to worry about `msg_id`. You have to pass only message related data excluding id. DBMS take care of `msg_id`.
- If you want to handle auto increment by manually then use this query. `SELECT MAX(msg_id) as next_id FROM msgs`.
- You also try any ORM package like Hibernate, JPA.