# the diference Java Connection method (ClassForname & RegisterDriver)

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, connection

I know about 2 ways to connect to database well I will divided it into 2 methods (Method1 and Method 2)

```
Connection connection;

public void getConnectionMethod1() {
    try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/latihan","sa","denni");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}

public void getConnectionMethod2() {
    try {
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver());
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/latihan","sa","denni");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
    }
}
```

My question is; is there any difference between them ? Method 1 uses `Class.forName` While method 2 uses `registerDriver`

What is the advantages and disadvantages between them?

NOTE : I can only use PreparedStatement on Method 2.

Comment: JDBC has not needed either of those for a long time now.  Just calling DriverManager.getConnection is sufficient.

Comment: VGR is correct. All newer JDBC drivers will auto-register. This is done by the file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` in the driver .jar file. If you driver.jar file has this entry, you don't need either method. If it doesn't, you should consider upgrading to a newer version of the driver.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver

Comment: As for your question, the main difference is that method 2 requires the driver to be present at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

From JDBC 4.0,Java developers no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using code like Class.forName() to register a JDBC driver. The DriverManager class takes care of this by automatically locating a suitable driver when the DriverManager.getConnection() method is called. This feature is backward-compatible, so no changes are needed to the existing JDBC code.