# Tomcat cannot find JDBC driver when connecting to DB

Tags: mysql, servlets, tomcat8

I've put mysql driver in `.../ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` and `Tomcat 8.0/lib` but it has no effect. I'm using the following class to connect to DB:

```
package db;

import java.sql.*;

public class ConnectToDB implements AutoCloseable {
    Connection con;

    public ConnectToDB(String server, String database, String user,
            String password) throws SQLException {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + server + "/"
                + database, user, password);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws SQLException {
        con.close();
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return con;
    }

}
```

The following classes are included in the Eclipse project:

**1. src/nr3/model**

```
package nr3.model;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import db.ConnectToDB;
public class MusikkHandler {
    private ConnectToDB db;
    private Connection con;
    private String tableName;
    private PreparedStatement pstmtGetRows;

    public MusikkHandler(String server, String database, String user,
            String password) throws SQLException {
        db = new ConnectToDB(server, database, user, password);
        con = db.getConnection();
        tableName = "album";
    }

    public void close() throws SQLException {
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<Album> getRows(String genre) throws SQLException {
        ArrayList<Album> list = new ArrayList<Album>();
        pstmtGetRows = con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tableName
                + " WHERE SJANGER = ?");
        pstmtGetRows.setString(1, genre);
        ResultSet rs = pstmtGetRows.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(new Album(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getInt(3),
                    rs.getInt(4), rs.getString(5)));
        }
        rs.close();
        pstmtGetRows.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

-

```
package nr3.model;

public class Album {
    private String tittel;
    private String artist;
    private int spor;
    private int utgitt;
    private String sjanger;

    public Album (String artist, String tittel, int spor, int utgitt, String sjanger){
        setArtist(artist);
        setTittel(tittel);
        setUtgitt(utgitt);
        setSpor(spor);
        setSjanger(sjanger);
    }
    public Album(){
        this(null, null, 0, 0, null);
    }
    public void setTittel(String tittel){
        this.tittel = tittel;
    }
    public void setArtist(String artist){
        this.artist = artist;
    }
    public void setSpor(int spor) {
        this.spor = spor;
    }
    public void setUtgitt(int utgitt) {
        this.utgitt = utgitt;
    }
    public void setSjanger(String sjanger) {
        this.sjanger = sjanger;
    }
    public String getTittel() {
        return tittel;
    }
    public String getArtist() {
        return artist;
    }
    public int getSpor() {
        return spor;
    }
    public int getUtgitt() {
        return utgitt;
    }
    public String getSjanger() {
        return sjanger;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return getTittel() + " (" + getArtist() + ")" + " Utgitt: " 
                                               + getUtgitt(); 
    }
}
```

**2. src/nr3/servlets**

```
package nr3.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import nr3.model.Album;
import nr3.model.MusikkHandler;

public class MusikkValg extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 428937262021570370L;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String genre = request.getParameter("sjanger");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        MusikkHandler mh;

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Musikk</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>MUSIKK-ANBEFALINGER</h1>");
        out.println("<br/>");
        out.println("<br/>");
        out.println("<h3>Da bør du kanskje forsøke en av disse:</h3>");
        out.println("<br/>");
        out.println("<br/>");
        try {
            mh = new MusikkHandler(" ", " ", " ", " ");
            for (Album a : mh.getRows(genre))
                out.println("<p>" + a + "</p>");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(out);
        }
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

}
```

Update: I've got the following error stacktrace in the browser:

> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost/pg3100 at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) at
>   db.ConnectToDB.(ConnectToDB.java:10) at
>   nr3.model.MusikkHandler.(MusikkHandler.java:20) at
>   nr3.servlets.MusikkValg.doGet(MusikkValg.java:39) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:534)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1081)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: do you get an Exception at runtime? does your code compile? Have you debugged your program? Which line is the problem?

Comment: MaVRoSCy, the code compiles in Eclipce. I've updated the info about the problem with stack trace.

Comment: Have you tried doing `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();` at some point before `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`?

Comment: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, you must register your driver at the beginning so DriverManager can user it when getting a connection. [It might vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver) on the implementation.

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
```

or

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

Then you can perform a `getConnection()` because you'll have a driver registered to be used by DriverManager.

Second: `/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib` is a different context and its libraries won't be available for your app unless you are setting the context path of your app [as shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276989/howto-set-the-context-path-of-a-web-application-in-tomcat-7-0). If you wanna add it, try placing your JDBC driver on `/webapps/<yourapp>/lib` first. Tomcat lib should work as well (but it's not nice when you distribute your app, might conflict with other apps deployed there, using different versions of the driver, etc.)

Third: When asking here, try to reduce your verifiable example to something readable. There's a lot of code which is not relevant to your problem. Reducing makes it easier to read your question and provide help.

Comment: Alfabravo, thank you for the answer and tips about using the site! Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  sentence solved the problem.

Comment: saved my day i was inserting it in my bin and class.forname() had a unknown resource... thank u