# what and where is "jdbc.drivers" system property?

Tags: java, jdbc

Curiously reading the javadoc of DriverManager, I saw this:

> As part of its initialization, the DriverManager class will attempt to load available JDBC drivers by using:
>   The jdbc.drivers system property[...].

src:https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

What is a system property? It means nothing to me, where on my IDE (eclipse for example?) can I lookup those "system properties"? Are they related to the compiler?
So naturally, if I knew what was such a "system property" I would know where to find that "jdbc.driver" system property.

The root of these questions is: because the DriverManager class doesn't need class.forname(*Driver*) to loads drivers anymore, so how am I **sure** that when I add my driver to the buildpath of my project DriverManager will find it?
Does this "system property" gets updated automatically?

Comment: "*What is a system property*" - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: It probably means the properties exposed by [`java.lang.System`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html)

Comment: A driver can also be loaded via the "service location mechanisms", see [JDBC Class.forName vs DriverManager.registerDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227/jdbc-class-forname-vs-drivermanager-registerdriver) for more details.

Comment: Please don't add things like `[solved]` to titles.

Comment: I just leave it like so? That won't gives readers the understanding my problem found a solution