# class not found com.mysql.jdbc.driver while connect JDBC wth servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I am getting class not found com.mysql.jdbc.driver error while connecting servlet with jdbc .But when I am connect alone with jdbc it works fine.

Comment: That means either that the driver JAR is not on the classpath (e.g. it isn't in the WAR file), or that you are using the wrong classname for the driver class.  It also probably means that you are using the outdated `Class.forName` approach for loading the driver.  See the Oracle JDBC tutorial for the recommended way.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227

Comment: I try both classname and add drivers also

Comment: Did you try the approach in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484227 ?   Note that this is a common problem, and the common solutions >do< work ... if you do them correctly.