# ClassNotFoundException Dependencies in IntelliJ

Tags: java, jdbc, intellij-idea

I'm getting the following error: ClassNotFoundException

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oracle.ojbdc6-11.2.0.1.0
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
  at uk.ac.ebi.mydas.examples.Conn.main(Conn.java:23)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
  at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

On my intelliJ IDE I'm pretty sure I've set the dependencies properly on Maven:
because on my External Libraries Folder, there's a "Maven: com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.1.0" package listed.

I'm assuming there's a problem with my code not being able address the class properly.

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.oracle.ojbdc6");
}
```

I realize that the jdbc drivers are not in the Maven repo, so I had to download it directly from the oracle website (correct version number) and load it to my library. I then added the pom.xml dependency successfully.

[image: Maven: ojdbc dependency installed]

Finally, here's my POM.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks!

**EDIT:
Problem still occurs despite class OracleDriver being addressed.**
[image]

**EDIT2:
Here's a look into my module/dependencies setup on InnteliJ**
[image]

Comment: That's not the right Driver name. That looks like a package/version name. Read the javadoc of the methods you use before using them.

Comment: I'll elaborate if you tell me what `Class.forName(String)` does.

Comment: it loads a class, statically

Comment: Is there a class called `com.oracle.ojbdc6` anywhere on your classpath? Or rather `com.oracle.ojbdc6-11.2.0.1.0`? You must be looking for either `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` or `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`. Those are your oracle jdbc driver classes (depending on the version).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while

Comment: The method doesn't seem to still find it. Perhaps I haven't made an actual classpath. However, via the picture I showed up there, I do have both those classes under maven

Comment: What maven repo are you using?

Comment: The maven repository is where maven gets the jars for the dependencies you list. I can't find the one you listed in http://mvnrepository.com/. But your editor shows it as downloaded, so...

Comment: I didn't get it from a repo. I downloaded the driver from Oracle due to it being propietary. The pom.xml was changed after I loaded it via: mvn install:install-file -Dfile=G:\jdbc\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle  -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.1.0 -Dpackaging=jar || and I simply added: <dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.1.0</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Maven should add it to your classpath by default. Search for how to add jars to classpath/buildpath on intellij (with and without maven).

Comment: For some reason the Maven hack I tried won't work. I tried adding jar manually and it worked. Thanks for the help Sotirios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old (jdbc3) way of loading jdbc drivers was to load them with `Class.forName(String)`. Each Driver probably had a static block that made them register themselves with the `DriverManager`.

The String you pass to `Class.forName(String)` is the fully qualified Class name of the Driver. Therefore, `com.oracle.ojbdc6` and `com.oracle.ojbdc6-11.2.0.1.0` are meaningless unless they are actual classes on your classpath.

Instead of `com.oracle.ojbdc6` in

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.oracle.ojbdc6");
}
```

use either `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` or `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`, which are both Driver classes. It depends on which version of the jdbc driver you are using.

Here's a related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while).

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me, Sotirios, I looked into the related answer and tried "java.lang.String" just to see if my string path was bad. Sure enough there's not complaint with the string class. I'm assuming this means I messed up with setting the classpath. How can I make sure I set it correctly?

Comment: Your classpath is probably right. Just change the class name to what I put in my answer. If not, if intellij has some search function, try to find the class. If you can find it, it's probably on your project classpath.

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it be ojdbc6 instead of ojbdc6?

Comment: Even if OP corrects that, will the driver he wants get loaded?