# Java - Using Annotations/Tags to find which object to make

Tags: java, object, tags, annotations

So let's say you have a class called Human, and a bunch of other classes that all extend Human (John, Sally, Mark). Human has an annotation "@Tags({"human"})", John has annotation "@Tags({"john"})", etc.. All classes have their corresponding tags.

My question is: how can I use these tags to figure out which object to make?

So like, a user will input either "john" "sally" or "mark" and I want to make that corresponding object...

Comment: Are the annotations essential? They seem like hard-coding to me, or is the example contrived to hide details/organisation/etc?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern):

> a software design pattern, whereby an algorithm's behaviour can be selected at runtime

You could use this pattern to match input to a factory or as part of an `enum` that maps the name to a given class type (though there are several "hard-coding" issues with this approach).

As for construction of object instances, I recommend you also look at the [Factory Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) and combine the two to create these objects in an abstract manner.

I also recommend you don't tag your objects lik this, as you're hard-coding user input expectations against your codebase. At least externalise such expectations to a configuration file (`.properties` or `.xml`) so the mappings of input can change independently of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar requirements in a Project.

This is what I did,

1. **Design a strategy to read the Class(s)**  : This is required because the classes are not referenced in any of your code directly. Hence these classes wont be processed by any ClassLoader automatically. [Load class dynamically using Class.forName()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while)
2. **Generate a Factory** : Make the scope of your annotation as Runtime. This will allow you to process the class files that you have read and extract your custom annotation value out of it. Then you can register the name of this class against the annotation in the factory class.
3. **Use the factory to generate the Objects** : Now you have a factory which can return the objects of your class when you pass a tag name. Use reflection to create a Object.

To know more about factory pattern please refer the link : [Factory Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html)