# cannot connect to mssql server from java jdbc

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, database-connection

I am trying to connect to mssql server from java but I couldnt figure it out. It throws an exception

`ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433;DatabaseName=MLS_J`

here is the code below. What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

```
public static String connection_test(){
    String address  = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.1.101:1433;DatabaseName=MLS_J";
    String user = "sa";
    String password = "xxxx";

    try {
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(address, user, password);
            java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            return "Bağlantı kapalımı? - " + conn.isClosed();


    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "ERROR: " + e.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you included ms sql jar in your build path?

Comment: ...or added maven dependency?

Comment: I havent done anything for build path. It was working before but suddenly it stopped working. How can I check that?

Comment: @ayilmaz see my answer to see how to add jar files in build path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while?lq=1).

Try adding this line to your code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
```

Comment: how do I add sqljdbc4.jar to my classpath?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Then just copy it into your project folder, right-click it and select "Build Path -> Add to Build Path"

Comment: Class.forName is not needed for JDBC 4 drivers. If the driver is on the classpath it will be loaded automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps for adding jar files in build path

1. Right click on project
2. click build path-> configure build path
3. click libraries folder
4. then click add external jar and give the path of the sqljdbc4.jar.

I would suggest you to use [jtds](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/) driver.