# Connect from Java to Hive using JDBC

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I'm trying to connect from Java to Hive server 1.
I found a question time ago in this forum but it doesn't work for me.
I'm using this code:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws SQLException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
      try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    //replace "hive" here with the name of the user the queries should run as
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "hive", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.execute("drop table if exists " + tableName);
    stmt.execute("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
       // describe table
    sql = "describe " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }


// load data into table
// NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
// NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
String filepath = "/tmp/a.txt";
sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
stmt.execute(sql);

// select * query
sql = "select * from " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
}

// regular hive query
sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (res.next()) {
  System.out.println(res.getString(1));
}
```

That's the code shown in the guide. I've copied hive-metastore, service, jdbc, exec, core and more .jar in the same path of the .java. 
When I compile it, I get this msg:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
    at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:14)
```

Does anybody know what's happening here?

Comment: Did you ensure that the driver class is loaded by the current classloader ? I have not done JDBC for years now, but should there be a `Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")` ? Also make sure that *hive-jdbc* JAR file is in the classpath.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
```

instead of

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

I hope you have added `Class.forName(driverName)` statement in your code

Comment: Hi! I've already changed the driverName and I get the same msg. What do you mean with class.forName(driverName) ? thanks :)

Comment: it is to establish the connection with your `HiveDriver` through java. read [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while)

Comment: do you mean replacing private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver" for class.forName(driverName) ?

Comment: San Krish, I have already typed that code and it isn't working yet :(

Answer (score 14):

I think in your question you said its Hive server 1. If so the driver name and connection string should be as follows:

```
"org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"

jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "")
```

If you are using Hive server 2 , then it should be as follows:

```
org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

jdbc:hive2://<host>:<port>/<db>
```

I have used the same sample as you given and I am able to connect Hive with following dependencies in my pom.xml

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-metastore</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- runtime Hive -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-common</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-beeline</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-shims</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-serde</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
        <artifactId>hive-contrib</artifactId>
        <version>0.12.0-cdh5.0.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
```

Comment: Hi! Did you just added those dependencies to the "pom.xml" stored in the hive folder?

Comment: No, In My maven project of the above java application.

Comment: satha, I've got this msg now... Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to localhost:10000/default: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Comment: So which means your hive server is down. Or please use the correct hive server details.

Comment: I know it is an old and solved question but I faced the same problem and solved it using only two dependencies (hive sql, and hadoop core). I hope that helps anyone in the future.

Comment: `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test2: Could not resolve dependencies for project test:test2:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.hive:hive-metastore:jar:0.12.0-cdh5.0.0, org.apache.hive:h`

Answer (score 2):

u need to change on two places

use this

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver"
```

instead of

```
private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";
```

and second is 
use this

```
jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/default", "", ""
```

instead of

```
jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", ""
```