# unable to connect to hive 3 via jdbc

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive

I followed the steps mentioned in https://luckymrwang.github.io/2018/03/14/Install-hive-on-Mac-with-Homebrew/ to install Apache Hive in Mac book using Homebrew. It installed the version of 3.1.2_3.

I used the command hive and created some tables.

I went to the beeline command line and issued the command `!connect jdbc:hive2://` (I did not specify any connection URL as the documentation said there is no need to specify if the hive is installed in the same system) and entered the password as hive and hive as configured in hive-site.xml. It successfully connected to the hive. I used the command `show tables` and verified that I am able to see the tables.

Now I try to connect the same via Java JDBC application.

**Dependencies:**

```
compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.1.0'
compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.3.0'
```

**Code:**

```java
Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");

Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

String table = "CUSTOMER";
statement.executeQuery("DROP TABLE " + table);
```

However, I keep getting the error as the connection refused. I am not sure whether the connection string is correct or not. Can you please help in resolving the issue?

This is the exception trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException
```

I ran hive in debug mode using the command `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console`. I didn't see any exceptions there as well.

You can find the hive-site.xml here. https://github.com/Jagannathan6/hive-site.xml/blob/main/hive-site.xml

```
echo $HADOOP_CLASSPATH in terminal gives the following.
```

```
/usr/local/Cellar/hadoop/3.3.0/libexec:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/hive-jdbc-3.1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/hive-exec-3.1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/hive-metastore-3.1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/hive-service-3.1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/libfb303-0.9.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/jdo-api-3.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/antlr-runtime-3.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-4.2.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/datanucleus-core-4.1.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-4.1.19.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/lib/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/hive/3.1.2_3/libexec/conf
```

The following jars are added in the classpath as well.

[image]

Comment: you are missing username and password in Driver.getConnection DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", username, password)

Comment: what is the default username and password? I haven't set any. So my guess it should be "" ?Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: what you are providing during login through command line?

Comment: according to your configuration username is `hiveuser10` and password is `password` then change `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");` to `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "hiveuser10", "password")`.

Comment: when i login with the command line. I do not provide any username and password. I just type hive and start typing the commands. I have tried with hiveuser10 and password as well. It didn't work.

Comment: check this [post](https://sparkbyexamples.com/apache-hive/hive-hiveexception-java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-org-apache-hadoop-hive-ql-metadata-sessionhivemetastoreclient/) maybe it would help.

Comment: I had done this earlier after which the operations from the command line worked. The problem I am facing is unable from jdbc program

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25157273/connect-from-java-to-hive-using-jdbc

Comment: this is the driver I am using it already

Comment: change `Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");` to `Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");` and also double check you have driver jar in the project. The compiler is not able to find `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException` class. replace your driver jar file

Comment: you are giving reference of `"org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver")` whereas it should be `org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` replace it and this will be fixed

Comment: Also change this ` DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive2://", "", "");` to `jdbc:hive2://localhost:<port>/default", "", "");`

Comment: I did both the changes you suggested. I have added the dependency.   compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.1.0'
   and 
    compileOnly 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-core:1.2.1'. Now I get this error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Answer (score -1):

Your original error of `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException` class not being found, indicates that you are missing the `hive-exec` jar in your class path, which houses the `HiveException` class.

Add the `hive-exec` jar to your dependency list.

```
    compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-jdbc:1.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-client:3.3.0'

    // add this dependency
    compile 'org.apache.hive:hive-exec:1.1.0'
```

Comment: What's the error you get? Still the class not found on hive exception?