# Can I connect to h2 embedded db without setting Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")?

Tags: java, database-connection, h2

Can I connect  to h2 embedded db without setting Class.forName("org.h2.Driver") ?
I used only those parameters: url, login and pass

```
 public static Connection getConnection()  {
    String url= ResourseHelper.getUrl();
    String user= ResourseHelper.getUser();
    String pass= ResourseHelper.getPass();

    try {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And than I create embedded database using this connection. And it works. Is it correct?

Comment: Seeing it work with your own eyes should be proof enough. Start worrying when you see an actual problem

Comment: maybe it works wrong :)

Comment: Yes but you identify that by seeing something actually being wrong. Right now you've seen it work. But if you must doubt everything you see, there are plenty of existing questions with answers that will ease your mind: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8053125/424903

Comment: Read tag descriptions before adding!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for Java 1.6 and newer, `Class.forName("org.h2.Driver")` is no longer needed. This is due to a change in JDBC 4.0. For details, see [Getting Connected Becomes Easier](http://web.archive.org/web/20150922213755/https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/10/whats-new-in-jdbc-40.html#getting-connected-becomes-easier).