# Retrieving all values from a column

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

How can I efficiently get all the values from a column via java through a SQL query without having to connect to the database with each subsequent call?

What I have now:

```
private List<String> retrieveSQLQuery(String sqlQuery) throws SQLException {
    JDBC jdbc = new JDBC();
    ResultSet rs = jdbc.getResultsSet(sqlQuery);
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        values.add(rs.getString("model"));
    }
    return values;        
}
```

However, for each subsequent `rs.next()`, it connects to the database, creates a statement and then retrieves the value.

It looks like this:

`Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
value1
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
value2
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
Connecting to database...
Creating statement...
Statement Created.
value3`

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

Edit:

Here is my resultset method:

```
public ResultSet getResultsSet(String QueryString) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        CachedRowSetImpl crs = null;
        try {
            // STEP 1: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName(jdbcDriver);

            // STEP 2: Open a connection
            logger.info("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);

            // STEP 3: Execute a query.
            logger.info("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = QueryString;
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            crs = new CachedRowSetImpl();
            crs.populate(rs);

            logger.info("Statement Created.");
            // STEP 5: Clean-up environment
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                if (stmt != null) {
                    stmt.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } // end try

        return crs;
    }
```

Comment: You should create a Simple, Self-Contained, Compilable Example http://sscce.org/. We don't know the types `JDBC` and its method `getResultsSet()`, for example, so it's hard to know what is wrong. The usual way to get a specific column from a table is for the query to select that column.

Comment: @LewBloch Going to edit now.

Comment: @LewBloch Please let me know if you need anymore information

Comment: You're closing the `ResultSet` before using it. Also the statement. Also the connection. It's a miracle you get any results back at all.

You also don't need to load the driver every time you call the method. `Class<?>.forName()` loads then initializes the driver class. Once that's done, it's loaded and initialized; you can't do it twice so the call is wasted code.

Comment: @LewBloch Hmm not sure what you mean?

Comment: What does `CachedRowSetImpl` accomplish? Can you post that too?

Comment: @sstan `CachedRowSetImpl` is a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiomatic way to retrieve data from the DB over JDBC is to

1. Get the `Connection`
2. Create a `Statement` on the `Connection`
3. Execute the `Statement`
4. Iterate through the returned `Resultset`

This means that for each query, you should only retrieve the `Connection` once and create a single `Statement`. Note that you shouldn't be *connecting to the database* each time you retrieve a `Connection`; you should be retrieving it from one of the many [connection pools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835090/how-to-establish-a-connection-pool-in-jdbc) available for JDBC. Also note that using `Class.forName(...)` for initializing the driver [is redundant for post-JDBC 4.0 drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while).

In short, it's better to operate on the JDBC API classes directly and not to roll your own wrappers/caching for these classes. Additionally, `Statement` and `ResultSet` objects should have a very limited scope (meaning that they shouldn't preferrably be passed between methods), in order to prevent resource leakage. JDBC resource management is also best and safest handled by using the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of the legacy `try-catch-finally` structure.

Keeping the above in mind, a rewrite of `retrieveSQLQuery()` (using only JDBC API classes, instead of your custom `JDBC` class) could look like the following:

```
 public List<String> retrieveSQLQuery(String sqlQuery) throws SQLException {

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery)) {

        while (rs.next()) {
            // this assumes that the passed-in query string has 
            // a "model" column in the SELECT clause
            values.add(rs.getString("model"));
        }
    }

    return values;        
}
```

Comment: Hey Mich, sorry to bother you again with this question but I am a bit confused. Is it not okay for me to create a custom JDBC class that can be used by other classes that needs to connect to the database to retrieve a query? Or should I just reuse the existing JDBC Api for every class that needs to connect to the database?

Comment: It is absolutely okay to create custom classes for data access -- however, this code should follow best practices (minimize scope of variables, ensure closing of resources etc).

Comment: I see. So by best practice I shouldn't return a resultset?

Comment: Usually you shouldn't do that (and when using try-with-resources you can't, because the result set is locally scoped and autocloseable). Of course, it always depends.. You could also post a question on codereview.stackexchange.com if you want some more comments on custom code.

Comment: THanks a buch, that helps a lot!