# How to secure Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)?

Tags: java, mysql, security, jdbc

I ran security scan on our application and one of the security issues that came up with is "Download of Code Without Integrity Check". This risk points of the line at `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

I have not able to find out

1. how do I secure the above line of code?
2. How do I make sure parameter for `forName("")` is not malicious class that I would be loading.

Note: I am using Java 1.7 on our live environment. We do not have a security policy/SecurityManager in place.

Edit: Security Scan used is Checkmarx.

Comment: Remove it. It hasn't been needed since 2007.

Comment: Yup that works. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [recent JDBC drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053095/what-is-the-actual-use-of-class-fornameoracle-jdbc-driver-oracledriver-while) there's no need to do the `Class.forName()` registration anymore. Update your driver if it's old (not JDBC4 or newer), and you'll be able to remove the line altogether.

The security issue seems to refer to [this](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/494.html) which would mean that the attacker has already access to the classpath, and therefore can cause plenty of damage in other ways as well. The suggested solution of checking a checksum at that point may not be of too much help.

Comment: Nevertheless, that still sounds like a bug in the report.

Comment: Could be, he didn't mention which tool he was using or on what basis it would flag that. It's also questionable why it talks about "Download of code".

Comment: That did work for me. But what if the class is not '"com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"'. How do you secure 'Class.forName();' then?