# No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver exception without Class.forname()

Tags: java, jdbc

I am getting *No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver* exception when I comment out first line.

I am using jdbc 4.1 and as https://stackoverflow.com/a/8053125/1379734 explained `Class.forName()` method is not necessary. What is wrong with my code?

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
con = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(getConnectionUrl(), userName, password);
```

Comment: Then you aren't using a JDBC4 compatible driver (or at least it isn't adhering to what it should do). The fact that you have a JDK that comes with JDBC 4.x doesn't mean that the driver you have is automatically a JDBC 4.x suitable driver. You will have to use the correct driver as well.

Comment: It sounds like you are using an invalid URL or a very old driver, a correct JDBC url for SQL Server starts with `jdbc:sqlserver:`, not `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver`. See also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

Comment: what version of the sql driver are you using? a compatible version should have a META-INF\services\java.sql.Driver file in it.

Answer (score 0):

The fact it works when you use `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` and a JDBC URL that starts with `jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver` indicates you are using the +/- 17 year old Microsoft SQL Server 2000 JDBC driver. This driver predates JDBC 4, so it does not support the driver auto-loading through `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`.

Since the SQL Server 2005 JDBC driver, the correct class name is `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver` (note that `jdbc` and `sqlserver` switched places) and the URL prefix changed to `jdbc:sqlserver:` (see also [this blogpost](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jdbcteam/2007/06/15/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-microsoft-jdbc-sqlserver-sqlserverdriver/)). I believe that JDBC 4 autoloading was added in the SQL Server 2008 JDBC driver. See [Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server) for more information.

If you want to take advantage of the driver auto-loading, you will need to upgrade your driver to a newer version (the latest preferably) and change your configuration.

See: https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-jdbc and the [Microsoft Download Center](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774)